# como hago para guardar los datos de los usuarios en un arreglo, y preguntar al usuario si quiere ingresar otro vehículo en python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def dato():
    canautos=30
    canmotos=10
    autos=[]
    motos=[]
    salidadelbehiculo=0
    conautos=0

print(" <<<<<-  BIENVENIDO AL PARQUEADERO DE JUAN  ->>>>> ")
print("")
while True:
    print(" ¿ QUE VEHICULO VAS A PAQUEAR ? : ")

    while True:
        print(" 1.CARRO ")
        print(" 2.MOTO ")
        op = int(input())
        break;
    else:
        print(" ERROR. tenga en cuenta las 2 opciones ")


    if op==1:
        for i in range(canautos):
            cupoautos=canautos-1
            if canautos>=cupoautos:
                print(" >>>>>-  INGRESE LOS SIGUIENTES DATOS DEL VEHICULO  -<<<<< :  ")
                print("")
                placa=input(" - placa del vehiculo :  ")
                fecha=int(input(" - fecha :  "))
                hora=float(input(" - hora de ingreso :"))
                autos=(" placa : ",placa) + (" fecha : ",fecha) + (" hora de ingreso : ", hora) 
                print(autos)
                break
                conautos=conautos+1
        #else:
            #rint(" lo sentimos no hay cupos por el momento. ")

    oop=input(" -- DESEAS SACACR UN AUTO -- (si/no)")
    if "si":
        for i in range(canautos):
            veri=(input(" ingrese la placa del vehiculo : "))
            if veri== placa:
                print(" la placa si esta registrada  ")
                break
            else:
                input(" la placa ingresada no EXISTE  ")

        tiempop=int(input(" hora de salida: "))
        if tiempop<=15:
            print(" el total a pagar es : ", 500 )
        if tiempop>16 and tiempop<=30:
            print(" el total a pagar es : ", 1000  )
        if tiempop>31 and tiempop<=45:
            print(" el total a pagar es : ",  1500)
        if tiempop>46 and tiempop<=60:
            print(" el total a pagar es : ", 2000)
        if tiempop>61:
            print(" el total a pagar es : ", 1800)
        calcutiempo= hora-tiempop
        print(" tiempo que permanecio el vehiculo en el parqueadero ",calcutiempo )
    salidadelbehiculo=canautos-1
    ganancias=tiempop
    print(" cantidad de vehiculos en el parqueadero", salidadelbehiculo )

opcion=input(" deseas ingresar otro auto si/no : ")

#return dato
# if opcion=="si":
    #for i in range(len(datos)):
        #  print(datos[i])
    #return dato
```

Comment: la variable `salidadelbehiculo` me duele al verla

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
import os,time,sys
from datetime import datetime

# dinero
precio=500
moneda="$"

# tiempo
tiempo=15       # 1 segundo
#tiempo=15*60   # 15 minuto

# parqueadero
canautos=10
cupoautos=0
autos=[]


def precios(k):
    i=0
    date=datetime.now()
    unix = int(round(date.timestamp()))
    for x in range(autos[k]["unix"],unix,tiempo): i+=1
    return precio*i

def valida_placa(placa):
    for k,v in enumerate(autos):
        if placa == autos[k]["placa"]:
            return k+1  #evita que devuelva 0 que es False
    else:
        return False

def parquear_autos():
    global cupoautos
    salir=True
    while(salir):
        if cupoautos < canautos:
            print(" >>>>>-  INGRESE LOS SIGUIENTES DATOS DEL VEHICULO  -<<<<< :  ")
            print("")
            nombre=input(" - Cual es su nombre :  ")
            placa=input(" - placa del vehiculo :  ")
            date=datetime.now()
            hora = str(date.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"))
            fecha =str(date.date())
            unix = int(round(date.timestamp()))
            valida = valida_placa(placa)

            if valida==False:
                print(f" nombre: {nombre} placa : {placa}, fecha : {str(fecha)}, hora de ingreso : {str(hora)}")
                print(" parqueado correctamente!")
                time.sleep(2)
                cupoautos+=1
                autos.append({"placa":placa,"fecha":date.date(),"hora":hora,"unix":unix})
                salir=False
            else:
                print(" no puedes ingresar 2 veces la misma placa!")
                time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print(f" lo sentimos no tenemos espacio la cantidad de autos es solo de: {canautos}")

def sacar_autos():
    global cupoautos
    placa=input(" - placa del vehiculo :  ")
    valida = valida_placa(placa)
    if valida:
        total = precios(valida-1)
        print(f" El total es de: {moneda}{str(total)}")
        time.sleep(2)
        del autos[valida-1]
        cupoautos-=1
        print("GRACIAS!")
        return True
    else:
        input(" la placa ingresada no EXISTE  ")
    return False

def parquear_motos():
    pass
def sacar_motos():
    pass


while True:
    os.system('cls')
    print(" <<<<<-  BIENVENIDO AL PARQUEADERO DE JUAN  ->>>>> ")
    print(f" nos quedan: {(canautos-cupoautos)} Puestos!")

    print(" ¿ PAQUEAR O SACAR ? : ")
    print(" 1.PAQUEAR ")
    print(" 2.SACAR ")

    try:
        op = int(input("> "))

        if op ==1:
            print(" ¿ QUE VEHICULO VAS A PAQUEAR ? : ")
            print(" 1.CARRO ")
            print(" 2.MOTO ")

            tipo = int(input("> "))
            if tipo ==1:
                parquear_autos()
            elif tipo ==2:
                parquear_motos()
            else:
                print("no es un opcion valida!")

        elif op ==2:
            print(" ¿ QUE VEHICULO VAS A SACAR ? : ")
            print(" 1.CARRO ")
            print(" 2.MOTO ")

            tipo = int(input("> "))
            if tipo ==1:
                sacar_autos()
            elif tipo ==2:
                sacar_motos()
            else:
                print("no es un opcion valida!")
                time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("no es un opcion valida!")
            time.sleep(2)

    except Exception as e:
        print("debes escribir solo el numero de la opcion")
```